# Eclipse Kepler crashes when launched on SLES 9.0 version

Tags: java, eclipse, suse

I have a problem when trying to launch eclipse 4.3.2 Kepler on SLES 9.0. 
I have installed java version 1.6.0_45 on suse linux enterprise server 9.0 SP3 (i586). 
Everytime i try to launch eclipse i am getting below error :

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0x40008016, pid=14444, tid=1085373360

JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.45-b01 interpreted mode, sharing linux-x86 )
Problematic frame:
C  [ld-linux.so.2+0x8016]  double+0xb6
```

Below are the details of java and suse linux version i am using for reference:

Any idea what could be the cause of this crash, i did'nt have a single succesful launch with this setup.